# Check if string name matches an asset in images.xcassets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcasset

Everything I google turns up answers about ALAsset's.

I have an images.xcassets folder and a bunch of assets in there.

I want to know if an asset exists in there based on a string.

E.g. `if(images.xcassets.contains("assetName") == true)`

Do you know how I can check if an asset exists based on a string?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do this specifically, but I would just create an UIImage with the resource image name you are checking and if the UIImage is nil then you know that resource is not available and can try another.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one way to check it.

```
NSString *someString = @"SomeStringFromSomwhere";

 if ([UIImage imageNamed: someString])
 { 
    //the image exists..
 } 
 else
 {
    //no image with that name
 }
```

Answer (score 17):

Just a bit more practical answer: **Swift**

```
if let myImage = UIImage(named: "assetName") {
  // use your image (myImage), it exists!
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Check whether image exist or not : **Swift 3**

```
if (UIImage(named: "your_Image_name") != nil) {
  print("Image existing")
}
else {
  print("Image is not existing")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift**, this is what I ended up using to assign either an existing asset or a default system image:

```swift
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "myAssetName") ?? UIImage(systemName: "photo")
// When former is nil, assigns default system image called "photo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with some combination of both and turned it into a function to use throughout my code.  I also want to return a default image if the one provided is missing.  (Swift 4 version)

```
func loadImage (named: String) -> UIImage {

    if let confirmedImage = UIImage(named: named) {
        return confirmedImage
    } else {
        return UIImage(named: "Default_Image.png")
    }

}
```

Then to load the image into something like a button you do something like this.

```
buttonOne.setImage(loadImage(named: "YourImage.png"), for: .normal)
```